# Navigate to a page after user sign up in the android app in flutter using FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working on phone authentication using flutter and firebase. So, when a user 'Register or Sign Up' for the app an OTP is received and then when he clicks the 'Login' button the phone number gets saved in the firebase but the page does not get loaded. After clicking the Login button, the account gets created but the page doesn't change and I have to close the app and open it again and the main page gets displayed. Please, tell me how to do it.

Code for **"Class SignUpView" :**

```
class SignUpView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpViewState createState() => _SignUpViewState();
}

class _SignUpViewState extends State<SignUpView> {

  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String phoneNo, verificationId, smsCode;

  bool codeSent = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Phone Number"),

                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.phoneNo = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),


           codeSent ? Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter OTP"),

                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.smsCode = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
           ): Container(),




            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Center(
                  child: codeSent ? Text("Login") : Text("Login"),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  codeSent? AuthService().signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationId):verifyPhone(phoneNo);
                  },
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verified = (AuthCredential authResult) {
      AuthService().signIn(authResult);
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (
        AuthException authException) {
      print('${authException.message}');
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsSent = (String verId, [int forceResend]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
      setState(() {
        this.codeSent = true;
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoTimeOut = (String verId) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };


    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNo,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verified,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: smsSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoTimeOut);
  }
}
```

The part of code where I need to add the navigation is:

```
 onPressed: () {
                  codeSent? AuthService().signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationId):verifyPhone(phoneNo);
}
```

There is another part of code- **Class AuthService:**

```
class AuthService {

  handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          return Home_Page();
        }
        else {
          return first_screen();  //Login();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds) {
    if(authCreds != null){
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
    }    
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode, verId) {
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
    signIn(authCreds);

  }

}
```

I tried to add navigation inside:

```
onPressed: () {
                  codeSent? AuthService().signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationId):verifyPhone(phoneNo);
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/create_account');
}
```

But this didn't worked as the above code would navigate to the page and the account won't be created.

I want that when the user type the OTP and then click the Login button, then his phone number should get verified and account should be created on firebase and then the user should be displayed another page. You can either use: **Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/create_account');** or **Account_setup_page()** for displaying the page.

I'd really be thankful for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to setup a stream for authentication changes in your AuthService class, i.e.

```
Stream<FirebaseUser> get user {
     return _auth.onAuthStateChanged; 
}
```

Then in your home screen (better in a wrapper widget) you could listen to that stream, so if the user is logged in, it will be redirected to the home screen, else it will be redirected to the sign in screen. This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); // listener for auth state
if (user == null) {
     return SignUpView();  // or the sign in view
} else {
     return Home(user: user,);  
     // home screen with the user as argument for easier access in the future
}
```

Maybe in the future when you will implement the sign out feature, this piece of code will automatically redirect the user to the sign in page

Comment: Thanks for your response @Aleksandar. I have this functionality which checks if the user is logged in it'll take him to the home page. But what I want is that when the user type the OTP and clicks on Login button, firebase should first authenticate the user, then create its account and then go to another page. I tried to do it using this: **Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/create_account');** but this doesnt helps.